# Assigning an argument to a global variable with the same name

Tags: python, scope, arguments, global

How can I assign a function argument to a global variable with the exact same name?

**Note:**
I can't do `self.myVariable = myVariable` because my function is not inside of a class.

When write the following code, I get an error saying that "argument is both local and global."

```
myVar = 1
def myFunction(myVar):
    global myVar
```

Is this impossible? and if so is it uncommon in other languages? Coming from java I'm used to `this.myVar = myVar`

**Edit** I already know that I can rename the variable.  That's the easy way out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Best solution: refactor your code. Rename something, or use an object with object properties instead of a global variable.

Alternative, hacky solution: modify the global variable dict directly:

```
my_var = 1
def my_function(my_var):
    globals()['my_var'] = my_var
```

Answer (score 1):

The best (and fastest) thing to do would be to take the easy way out and rename the variable(s). But if you insist, you could get around the naming conflict with this:

```
import sys
_global = sys.modules[__name__]
# or _globals = sys.modules[__name__].__dict__

myVar = 1
def myFunction(myVar):
    _global.myVar = myVar  # or _globals['myVar'] = myVar

print myVar  # 1
myFunction(42)
print myVar  # 42
```

**Explanation:**

Within a module, the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable`__name__`. The name`sys.modules`refers to a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have already been loaded. If`myFunction()`is running, its module has been loaded, so at that time`sys.modules[__name__]`is the module it was defined within. Since the global variable`MyVar`is also defined in the module, it can be accessed using `sys.modules[__name__].myVar`. (To make its usage similar to java, you could name it`this`-- but personally I think`_global`is a better.)

In addition, since a module’s read-only`__dict__`attribute is its namespace -- aka the global namespace -- represented as a dictionary object,`sys.modules[__name__].__dict__` is another valid way to refer to it.

Note that in either case, new global variables will be created if assignments to non-existent names are made -- just like they would be with the `global` keyword.

Comment: can you explain `sys.modules[__name__]`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to trick Python into doing it.  In your code:

```
myVar = 1
def myFunction(myVar):
    global myVar
```

myFunction is never run (you never call it).  So, the script never gets to the `global myVar` point.  Yet, Python still blows up for some reason.  I believe that that is because it has been told "Don't allow this".  Regardless, you can trick it into doing what you want.  One way that hasn't been suggested is to use a simple function in myFunction:

```
myVar = 1
def myFunction(myVar):
    def trick(arg):
        global myVar
        myVar = arg
    trick(myVar)

print myVar # Comes back with 1
myFunction(22)
print myVar # Comes back with 22
```

May not be on one line, but you don't have to import anything and it is easier to read.

Comment: thats the cleanest solution yet and it would work nicely with 20+ arguments like I need, any reason to use this over globals()?

Comment: @Stephan:  Well, I can't see any _technical_ reasons why.  They do the same things at heart.  However, it is a lost easier to read and maintain.  Also, being how Python gives you a global keyword, it seems more Pythonic (at least to me) to use that rather than the globals built-in (which can also be redefined).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could simply use a setter

```
myVar = 1
def myFunction(myVar):
    set_my_var(myVar)

def set_my_var(value):
    global myVar
    myVar = value
```